# How to find the number of days between LocalDate java?

Tags: java, java-8

I've got two `LocalDate`s:

```
LocalDate date1;
LocalDate date2;
//...
```

How to find the number of days between those dates?

Answer (score 19):

[`LocalDate.until`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) is what you're looking for. (LocalDate implements Temporal, which is what Days accepts, and ChronoUnit is a library of TemporalUnit instances.)

```
long days = date1.until(date2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
```

Answer (score 8):

I would do something like

```
long daysBetween = DAYS.between(date1, date2);
```

Comment: `ChronoUnit.DAYS` to be specific.